# Ionic starter templates user intro

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, ionic-framework

I was just watching a tutorial about Ionic and angularjs 
and in that tutorial creating Ionic project by just typing 
$yo ionic

when it comes to starter templates there were many choices one of them is user intro
and when i try to do i got only three templates 
slide menu, tabs and blank

anybody know why ?

the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gApduktFwxw

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is antiquated now, and the generator option showed in, is no longer available. You should still be able to accomplish the same thing with any of the generators though.